# Sharing information between a python code and c++ code (IPC)

Tags: python, c++, ipc

I have 2 code bases, one in python, one in c++. I want to share real time data between them. I am trying to evaluate which option will work best for my specific use case:

- many small data updates from the C++ program to the python program
- they both run on the same machine
- reliability is important
- low latency is nice to have

I can see a few options:

- One process writes to a flat file, the other process reads it. It is non scalable, slow and I/O error prone.
- One process writes to a database, the other process reads it. This makes it more scalable, slightly less error prone, but still very slow.
- Embed my python program into the C++ one or the other way round. I rejected that solution because both code bases are reasonably complex, and I prefered to keep them separated for maintainability reasons.
- I use some sockets in both programs, and send messages directly. This seems to be a reasonable approach, but does not leverage the fact that they are on the same machine (it will be optimized slightly by using local host as destination, but still feels cumbersome).
- Use shared memory. So far I think this is the most satisfying solution I have found, but has the drawback of being slightly more complex to implement.

Are there other solutions I should consider?

Comment: Directly using Python/C++ code from C++/Python?

Comment: RESTful API should help you most, A perfect language independent api

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, I own the 2 code bases, so yes I can use code directly in each.

Comment: It strongly depends on what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe Swig is also a good option.

Comment: Apache Thrift is a ZeroMQ alternative, with the plus of a language independent RPC framework.

Comment: @AntonioPérez they are not exactly alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062212/difference-between-apache-thrift-and-zeromq

Comment: @Andrey right, I didn't make my statement clear. If the OP wants to communicate processes in Python and C++, besides ZMQ, (s)he will need some kind of common serialization mechanism like JSON, msgpack or Protobuf. Then Thrift is an alternative to (ZMQ+serialization mechanism)

Comment: @JesperFreesbug can you elaborate on swig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this question is highly opinion-based!

The cleanest way would be to use them in the same process and get them communicate directly. The only complexity is to implement proper API and C++ -> Python calls. Drawbacks are maintainability as you noted and potentially lower robustness (both crash together, not a problem in most cases) and lower flexibility (are you sure you'll never need to run them on different machines?). Extensibility is the best as it's very simple to add more communication or to change existing. You can reconsider maintainability point. Can you python app be used w/o C++ counterpart? If not I wouldn't worry about maintainability so much.

Then shared memory is the next choice with better maintainability but same other drawbacks. Extensibility is a little bit worse but still not so bad. It can be complicated, I don't know Python support for shared memory operation, for C++ you can have a look at Boost.Interprocess. The main question I'd check first is synchronisation between processes.

Then, network communication. Lots of choices here, from the simplest possible binary protocol implemented on socket level to higher-level options mentioned in comments. It depends how complex your C++ <-> Python communication is and can be in the future. This approach can be more complicated to implement, can require 3rd-party libraries but once done it's extensible and flexible. Usually 3rd-party libraries are based on code generation (Thrift, Protobuf) that doesn't simplify your build process.

I wouldn't seriously consider file system or database for this case.

Comment: What is "proper API" in this case? I don't get it. They are separate apps.

Comment: I mean an API that you'd like to call from C++ side, it can be whatever you need, but better to keep it in a single place, something like façade pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), for painless maintenance. Such an API would be fine to have no matter what options you choose.